# remove elements of a vector from another vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I have two vectors of XML DOM nodes:

```
vector<IXMLDOMNodePtr> A; //filled in somehow
vector<IXMLDOMNodePtr> B; //filled in somehow
```

B is a subset of A. I want to remove B from A and I also want to preserve the order of A, so that if an element in A is removed it is replaced with a blank element. It would look like this:

```
node1||blank||node2||...
```

The `remove_if` function from `<algorithm>` may do the job, but i don't know how to code the predicate function here. Does anyone know what the predicate function should look like?

update:

I tried the following code:

```
static MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr transformIfInB(const vector<MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr>& B,     MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr ptr){return find(B.begin(), B.end(), ptr) != B.end() ? 0 : ptr;
}};

std::transform(vecCurRowItemSet.begin(),vecCurRowItemSet.end(),vecCurRowItemSet.begin(),std::bind1st(transformIfInB, vecTempItemSet));
```

vecCurRowItemSet and vecTempItemSet are all of vectors of IXMLDOMNodePtr
but i got the following errors:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(278): error C2825:     '_Fn2': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>          XMLDOMFromVCDlg.cpp(4161) : see reference to class template instantiation     'std::binder1st<_Fn2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fn2=MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr (const std::vector<MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr>     &,MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr)
1>          ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is a perfect algorithm for you in the standard library. The amount of work depends on whether the two vectors are pre-sorted or not, or if you can sort them.

If you cannot sort your vectors, then you are left in O(n^2) territory, since for each element in B to be removed from A, you have to search A once over to find it.

A good sort is O(n lg n), so pre-sorting is faster than not sorting them, in general.

If performance is not an issue, the brute force approach is

```
IXMLDOMNodePtr transformIfInB(IXMLDOMNodePtr ptr) { return find(B.begin(),B.end(), ptr) != B.end() ? 0 : ptr; }
...
std::transform(A.begin(),A.end(),A.begin(),transformIfInB);
```

If the two vectors are sorted, perhaps better to iterate through them in parallel

```
typedef std::vector<IXMLDOMNodePtr>::iterator vecIt;
vecIt itA, itB;
std::sort(A.begin(),A.end()); 
std::sort(B.begin(),B.end());
for(itA = A.begin(), itB = B.begin(); itB != B.end() && itA != A.end(); )
{
  if(*itA < *itB) ++itA; 
  else if(*itA == *itB) *itA++ == 0;
  else if(*itA > *itB ) ++itB;
}
```

In this loop, we hold two iterators into B and A. We move A forward while it is less than B - therefore we know there are no elements before this in A that exist in B, because they are sorted. We move B forward if the inverse is true. If they match, we zero the element per your question.

Comment: i didnt find a sort function in vector

Comment: My bad, try `std::sort(A.begin(),A.end()); std::sort(B.begin(),B.end());`

Comment: in the brutal force solution, the parameter list should include vector<IXMLDONNodePtr> B?

Comment: i mean can i integrate transformIfInB into std::transform, since both A and B are declared as local vectors in my program.

Comment: You can using bind1st. Change the predicate to a binary function, and use bind1st to set B:
`IXMLDOMNodePtr transformIfInB(const std::vector<IXMLDOMNodePtr>& B, IXMLDOMNodePtr ptr) { return find(B.begin(),B.end(), ptr) != B.end() ? 0 : ptr; }
std::transform(A.begin(),A.end(),A.begin(),std::bind1st(transformIfInB, B));
`

Comment: i think i can also use a overloaded operator(), but i am not quite sure how to do that, could you give me a hint?

Comment: You're in the same position with overloading () - that gives you function semantics on a class instance, so give a class P with overloaded () you would give it a private field B set in the constructor. Then `transform(A.begin(),A.end(),A.begin(),P(B));`
bind1st and related functions achieve the same - to give your function access to data it wouldn't otherwise be able to. 
`bind1st`, given a value `v` and function `f(a,b)`, creates a function `f(b') => f(v,b')`.

STL can then invoke `f(b')` in unary form, as they expect to, and you can implement your predicate `f(a,b)` - just as you want to.

Comment: hi, i updated some progress in the post, had a compilation error actually,

Comment: I misled you, and myself too - my apologies. bind1st can only work on functors, just as you proposed with operator(). Here is the code:
`class txifinb : public std::binary_function<std::vector<MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr>*,MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr,MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr> {
 public: 
   result_type operator() ( first_argument_type B, second_argument_type ptr) const {
     return std::find(B->begin(), B->end(), ptr) != B->end() ? 0 : ptr;
   }
};


int main() {
  std::vector<MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr> A,B; 
  std::transform(A.begin(),A.end(),A.begin(),std::bind1st(txifinb(), &B));
  return 0;
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you guarantee that `B` is an ordered subsequence of `A`, you could write this yourself:

```
auto j = B.begin();
for (auto i = A.cbegin(); i != A.cend(); ++i)
{
  if (*i == *j) { *i = blank; ++j; }
}
assert(j == B.end());
```

---

OK, for the general case, where `B` isn't necessarily in the correct order. Using predicates is no good, because the predicate must have a **const** call, and we need to manipulate the object (or some other state variable). So let's try a variation of the above instead:

```
auto j = B.begin();

std::set<size_t> Bindices;
for (size_t i = 0; i < B.size(); ++i) { Bindices.insert(Bindices.end(), i); }

for (auto i = A.cbegin(); i != A.cend(); ++i)
{
  for (auto k = Bindices.begin(); k != Bindices.end(); ++k)
  {
    if (*i == B[*k]) { *i = blank; Bindices.erase(k); break; }
  }
}

assert(Bindices.empty());
```

Comment: whats "auto"? and is "blank" is keyword in VC++? I am really new to these usages.

Comment: @Kerrek, this will only work if B is a subsequence of A (as opposed to a subset).

Comment: `auto` is C++0x, since you say Visual Studio I thought you have it. If not, say `std::vector<IXMLDOMNodePtr>::const_iterator i;` and `std::vector<IXMLDOMNodePtr>::iterator j;`. (Now you wish you hadn't asked!) `blank` is what you told us in the question... just put whatever you want in there.

Comment: Hm, I think the STL algorithms all just work on sorted ranges (in which case my algorithm would also work), but if we're to leave the original range in order, then I can only think of replacing the loop body by a more complicated check.

Comment: OK, I added a slightly more involved version that tracks the indices of elements in `B`.